# mongo shell cat() file to big to load as a variable at

Tags: javascript, mongodb, performance, cat, mongo-shell

I have javascript that I load to mongo to get some info.

```
mongo --port=27017 script.js
```

I am passing ObjectIds from the file as a variable:

```
#script.js

db=connect('127.0.0.1:27017/dbname')
db.auth('user', 'pass') //get credentials


var file = cat('file_with_ids.txt');  // read the file
var objectId = file.split('\n');
for (var k =0, j = objectId.length-1; k<j; k++){
    someFunction(objectId[k])

}
```

It works with files with (500K rows), but I have files with 1.5 M and more records that I need to work on. 
I was not successful finding documentation on mongodb cat() and its internals.
I know that I can split the file into chunks and feed one by one using **bash script**, but I do not want to go that route. 
Limitations:
**I can only use pure JS**, no node (could have been easier).  I have written python code to do it, it works but python (pymonogo) reorders the order of the documents.

Any suggestions? How to solve this in pure JS? Thanks

Comment: The `mongo` shell provides a limited programming environment as compared to a full driver implementation like Python. It sounds like you are already aware of better approaches: use a normal driver (eg. PyMongo) or split your input into smaller batches and try to work around the limitations of the `mongo` shell. The Python approach would be much more robust if you want proper I/O and error handling. If your Python code isn't working as expected you should perhaps post a question with relevant code and what you are trying to achieve.